How to filter a list of DTOs based on a list of search criteria?
I am trying to implement filtering on a list of EmployeeDTOs. I have a list of SearchCritera which I want to be imposed on the list for the filtering. Here are the class structures.
public class EmployeeDTO {
    private String id;
    private String employeeId;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String middleName;
    private LocalDate dob;
    private Map<String, Object> details; // for storing dynamic nested data
}

public class SearchCriteria {
    private String key;
    private String value;
    private SearchCondition condition;
    private SearchOperation operation;
}

public enum SearchCondition {
    EQUALS, CONTAINS, STARTS_WITH, ENDS_WITH, GREATER_THAN, LESS_THAN, GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUALS, LESS_THAN_OR_EQUALS
}

public enum SearchOperation {
    AND, OR, NOT
}

You can expect the list of SearchCriteria to be something list this:
[
    {
        "key": "education.degree", 
        // would reside in details.education.degree where education is an array of {degree, city}
        "value": "BBA",
        "condition": "EQUALS"
    },
    {
        "key": "education.degree",
        "value": "MBAA",
        "condition": "EQUALS",
        "operation": "AND"
    },
    {
        "key": "education.degree",
        "value": "BA",
        "condition": "EQUALS",
        "operation": "OR"
    },
    {
        "key": "middle_name",
        "value": "Anne",
        "condition": "EQUALS",
        "operation": "NOT"
    }
]

This is what I implemented to filter the list of Employees. But I'm getting inaccurate results based on this filtering technique. I must be going wrong somewhere.
public class EmployeeFilter {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeFilter.class);
    private static final String OUTPUT_1 = "output_1";
    private static final String OUTPUT_2 = "output_2";

    public Map<String, JSONObject> processNode(List<EmployeeDTO> employees, List<SearchCriteria> searchCriteria) {
        Map<String, List<EmployeeDTO>> filteredEmployees = filterEmployees(employees, searchCriteria);

        JSONObject validEmployeesJson = new JSONObject();
        validEmployeesJson.put(Constants.EMPLOYEES, filteredEmployees.get("valid"));

        JSONObject invalidEmployeesJson = new JSONObject();
        invalidEmployeesJson.put(Constants.EMPLOYEES, filteredEmployees.get("invalid"));

        return Map.of(
            OUTPUT_1, validEmployeesJson,
            OUTPUT_2, invalidEmployeesJson
        );
    }

    private Map<String, List<EmployeeDTO>> filterEmployees(List<EmployeeDTO> employees, List<SearchCriteria> searchCriteria) {
        Map<Boolean, List<EmployeeDTO>> partitionedEmployees = employees.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(e -> isEmployeeMatchingSearchCriteria(e, searchCriteria)));

        return Map.of(
            "valid", partitionedEmployees.getOrDefault(true, Collections.emptyList()),
            "invalid", partitionedEmployees.getOrDefault(false, Collections.emptyList())
        );
    }

    private boolean isEmployeeMatchingSearchCriteria(EmployeeDTO employee, List<SearchCriteria> searchCriteria) {
        boolean result = true;

        for (SearchCriteria criterion : searchCriteria) {
            boolean match = evaluateCondition(employee, criterion);

            SearchOperation currentOperation = criterion.getOperation();
            if (currentOperation == null) currentOperation = SearchOperation.AND;

            result = switch(currentOperation) {
                case AND -> result && match;
                case OR -> result || match;
                case NOT -> !match;
            };
        }

        return result;
    }

    private boolean evaluateCondition(EmployeeDTO employee, SearchCriteria criterion) {
        String key = criterion.getKey();
        String val = criterion.getValue();
        SearchCondition condition = criterion.getCondition();

        Object employeeValue = getValue(employee, key);

        if(employeeValue == null) return false;

        switch (condition) {
            case EQUALS:
                if (employeeValue instanceof List) {
                    List<?> list = (List<?>) employeeValue;
                    return list.stream().anyMatch(item -> item.equals(val));
                }
                return employeeValue.equals(val);
            
            case CONTAINS:
                return employeeValue.toString().contains(val);
            case STARTS_WITH:
                return employeeValue.toString().startsWith(val);
            case ENDS_WITH:
                return employeeValue.toString().endsWith(val);
            case GREATER_THAN:
                return compareValues(employeeValue, val) > 0;
            case LESS_THAN:
                return compareValues(employeeValue, val) < 0;
            case GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUALS:
                return compareValues(employeeValue, val) >= 0;
            case LESS_THAN_OR_EQUALS:
                return compareValues(employeeValue, val) <= 0;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    private int compareValues(Object employeeValue, String val) {
        try {
            if (employeeValue instanceof Number) {
                double employeeDouble = ((Number) employeeValue).doubleValue();
                double valDouble = Double.parseDouble(val);
                return Double.compare(employeeDouble, valDouble);
            } else if (employeeValue instanceof String) {
                return ((String) employeeValue).compareTo(val);
            } else if (employeeValue instanceof LocalDate) {
                LocalDate employeeDate = (LocalDate) employeeValue;
                LocalDate valDate = LocalDate.parse(val, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                return employeeDate.compareTo(valDate);
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private Object getValue(EmployeeDTO employee, String key) {
        if (employee == null || key == null) { // Added null check for employee
            return null;
        }

        switch (key) {
            case "employee_id": return employee.getEmployeeId();
            case "email": return employee.getEmail();
            case "first_name": return employee.getFirstName();
            case "middle_name": return employee.getMiddleName();
            case "last_name": return employee.getLastName();
            case "phone": return employee.getPhone();
            case "dob": return employee.getDob();
            default:
                // Handle dot notation (for nested objects), including arrays
                Map<String, Object> details = employee.getDetails();
                String[] keys = key.split("\\.");
                Object value = details;

                for (String part: keys) {
                    if (value instanceof Map) {
                        value = ((Map<String, Object>) value).get(part); // navigating the map
                    } else if (value instanceof List) {
                        List<?> list = (List<?>) value;
                        List<Object> matchedValues = new ArrayList<>();
                        
                        for (Object item: list) {
                            if(item instanceof Map) {
                                Object nestedValue = ((Map<String, Object>) item).get(part);
                                if (nestedValue != null) {
                                    matchedValues.add(nestedValue);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        value = matchedValues; 
                    } else {
                        return null; // neither a map nor a list
                    }

                    // If it is nested further
                    if (value != null && !part.equals(keys[keys.length - 1])) {
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        // Found deepest value
                        return value;
                    }
                }
                return null;
        }
    }
}


Please help me correct the logic and it would also be helpful if you could suggest some code improvements that I can make. Thanks in advance!

Ideal would be to filter on the DB side, instead of after you've already retrieved data you don't want and built DTOs for it.

In any case, the intended interpretation of your criteria data is unclear to me (and maybe to you, too).  Is it intended that the AND operation should have the same precedence as the OR operation?  Is the NOT operation intended to mean "AND NOT"?  And are all these intended to associate from left to right? That's all feasible, but it's different from conventional boolean logic.  I don't think your data structure is sufficient to represent conventional boolean expressions.

Hi John, thanks for the quick response. Although I've named it DTO, I'm sourcing the data from DB as well as from external sources. So by the time I filter, I'll have mixed data hence a DB filter query isn't an option. I would love to follow boolean algebra, but I know that it is hard to achieve hence I've decided to go with left-to-right and same precedence for OR and AND. You're right, NOT represents AND NOT

Those details of the intended meaning of your operators should be edited into the question.

I think the way you have the search criteria is misleading.
Also considering that NOT is not actually used in the same context as AND and OR.
Essentially, AND and OR are used to join 2 operations, while NOT to negate one.
An abstraction of what a search condition is would look like:
left Predicate AND/OR right Predicate

So you can consider the Predicate as an interface, that you already have in Java.
Using this, you can implement different predicates, for example:
private Predicate<EmployeeDTO> createPredicate(SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
  return switch(searchCriteria.type) {
    case "AND" -> createPredicate(searchCriteria.left).and(createPredicate(searchCriteria.right));
    case "OR" -> createPredicate(searchCriteria.left).or(createPredicate(searchCriteria.right));
    case "NOT" -> Predicate.not(createPredicate(searchCriteria.left));
    case "EQUALS" -> __ -> Objects.equals(retrieveValue(searchCriteria.field), searchCriteria.value);
    // and other operation types
  }

}

You would use it like this:
public List<EmployeeDTO> filterEmployees(List<EmployeeDTO> employees, SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
  Predicate<EmployeeDTO> predicate = createPredicate(searchCriteria);
  return employees.stream().filter(predicate).toList();
}

Given this structure, you can redesign the search criteria like this:
{
  type: "OR",
  left: {
    type: EQUALS,
    field: "education.degree",
    value: "BBVA"
  },
  right: {
    type: EQUALS,
    field: "education.degree",
    value: "BA"
  }

}

Now you have a clear way to define the order of operations, and to extend it with additional operation types.

The OP's logical operators are different from the conventional boolean logic, as is already covered in comments.  That might be an issue for users, but "misleading" is not how I would describe it.  For what it's worth, various aspects of conditional logic along the OP's lines are known in the Unix shell and the Unix find utility, so they are precedented.

In any case, although the headline question is pretty broad (too broad if that were the actual question), what the OP seems actually to want to know is what's wrong with the code presented ("Please help me correct the logic"), not how to design an alternative from scratch.

Inasmuch as you clarified in comments that your NOT operator is intended in the sense of "and not", the code presented handles that operator incorrectly.  This ...

                case NOT -> !match;


... considers only the value of the current term, ignoring the running result up to that point.  It is not a faithful implementation of "and not".  You appear to want ...
                case NOT -> result && !match;

... instead.
